# Self referencing relationships with own relation entity (spring data jpa / hibernate)

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, self-reference

I am trying to build an application which uses access-control for all attributes of an entity. So an user can see for example an image of a location but not its name. It works fine but I am running into trouble while implementing self-referencing entities with spring data jpa.

For example I have locations which each can have up to 1 parent locations. The 'typical' way to self-reference the Location entity and just drop the relationship entity won't work for my use case because of the attribute-detailed access-control. An user could see both locations but don't know they are connected.

I tried different ways but just cannot figure out the right way. I guess I am overlooking some fundamentals.

My location looks like this (at the moment):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOCATION")
@SequenceGenerator(name="locationId", sequenceName="LOCATION_SEQUENCE", initialValue=1, allocationSize = 1)
public class LocationEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "locationId")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "TYPE")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private LocationType locationType;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_RELATION")
    private LocationRelationshipEntity parentRelationship;
```

My relationship looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOCATION_RELATIONSHIP")
@SequenceGenerator(name="locationRelationshipId", sequenceName="LOCATION_RELATIONSHIP_SEQUENCE", initialValue=1, allocationSize = 1)
public class LocationRelationshipEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "locationRelationshipId")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="PARENT")
    private LocationEntity parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parentRelationship")
    private Set<LocationEntity> children = new HashSet<>();
```

This kinda works but with each update a new entry in the relationship table is created.

For example for the location with the ID 10 I have multiple entries in the LocationRelationship-Table for the same parent ID 11.

I also tried the following at first:

**LocationEntity:**

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<LocationRelationshipEntity> relationships;
```

**LocationRelationshipEntity**

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT")
    private LocationEntity parent;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CHILD")
    private LocationEntity child;
```

This also works more or less because it forces me to always check before saving a parent location if it has children. If it does I have to load the children before saving. Otherwise a parent location forgets its children when its updated. This I would like to avoid. Especially because it makes handling the attribute-access-control more complicated and its already complicated enough.

**Long story short:**

I would love to have a LocationEntity with just a singular reference to a parent location(relationship). Saving and updating the location should not produce multiple entries for the same parent.

Any ideas? Or am I better off with just forgetting about the auto-referencing and cascades with hibernate / spring data and just do the persistence of LocationRelationships myself?